# (Discord.js) Discord emojis break when used in a server different from their original server

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am developing a trading cards bot, but a problem I ran into was not being able to fit all of the card emojis into the main development server because of the emoji limit, so I chose to add all of them to a different server and invite the bot there so they can use them. I tested my commands in the server I made to house the emojis, and all the menus worked just fine as I switched pages, with all the emojis properly displaying. However when I switched to the development server, the emojis would only display properly the first time I initiated a command, and whenever I switched pages (aka updating the interaction reply) the emojis would break into their literal names. Screenshots below:

**Triggering the shop command, page 1**

[image: shop page 1]

**After going to page 2, then going back to page 1**

[image: shop page 1 edited]

The command being executed in the emoji server and development server is the exact same (No, its not one of them being a global command and being slow to update, both are guild commands), the syntax for using emojis from other servers is right (<:DeathRare:1125267015867846686>, <:PilotedRare:1125267035572682783>), so why is it that it works in one and doesn't in the other? Is there even a solution to this besides boosting my development server so it can fit all of the card emojis without a need for another server?

EDIT: The issue was resolved. I did a search regarding the issue, and it turns out that setting the @everyone role to have the External Emojis permission in the channel (instead of just the role) the command was being used in fixed the issue. Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: I don't remember if this is still relevant, but does the "everyone" role in the server where the command is ran have external emojis permission?

Comment: are you on desktop/web or mobile?

Comment: @itzJOH_ Yes the everyone role can use external emojis

Comment: @DarshanB Desktop

Comment: Are you using `.followUp()` (with `deferReply`) or `.editReply()` ? Because I believe there was a bug (on discords side, not discordjs) regarding external emojis. Can you try a simple `.send()` instead and let us know if that works?

Comment: @NullDev Yes I am using .reply() and then .editReply() to update the bot's response. I did a search regarding the issue since you said it was a recognized bug, and it turns out that setting the everyone role to have the External Emojis permission in the channel (instead of just the role) the command was being used in fixed the issue. Its quite funky behaviour but I am glad that I was able to fix it at least haha, thank you everyone for the help!